# How do I use Avatar Image URLs from the Azure Devops API

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I'm currently working on a dashboard type application which interacts with the Azure Devops API using the C# client libraries. I connect like so:

```cs
var devOpsApi = new VssConnection(url, credentials);
```

And I can successfully retrieve the Team Image URLs when requesting project details:

```cs
var projectsClient = devOpsApi.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();
var projects = await projectsClient.GetProjects(getDefaultTeamImageUrl: true);
```

However, when I try to render this image in an `<img>` tag on my dashboard it does not display, and when inspecting the image in firefox I see the tooltip "Could not load the image". Clicking the link and Navigating directly to the image URL displays the image though.

Assumedly this is a permissions or CORS issue as when I try to view the page in incognito mode, the request gets redirected to the azure devops login page.

So to summarize: is there a way I can use these image URLs on a page that isn't azure devops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can not use the image URLs on a page that isn't Azure DevOps unless you provided the correct credential to login Azure DevOps first in that page.

Then you can get the image with REST API : [Avatars - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/avatars/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

[image]

Another similar thread for your reference : [VSO REST API - Getting user profile image only works with basic authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577391/vso-rest-api-getting-user-profile-image-only-works-with-basic-authentication)

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for but I guess its the best I'll get- thanks. :)